# Authentication failure with OAuth to Traefik dashboard

Tags: traefik, traefik-authentication

I am trying to get Traefik setup in a Docker and am having a heck of a time. Following [this guide](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-2-docker-tutorial/) and using Cloudflare (DNS only to trafeik.mydomain.com), to connect, I am getting "This site can't be reached oauth.mydomain.com's server IP address could not be found".

```
wget https://traefik.mydomain.com/dashboard
--2020-09-26 19:19:38--  https://traefik.mydomain.com/dashboard
Resolving traefik.mydomain.com (traefik.mydomain.com)... <ip address>
Connecting to traefik.mydomain.com (traefik.mydomain.com)|<ip address>|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 307 Temporary Redirect
Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=6597174190-33npvgec044jtcrj4scmfgt561.apps.googleusercontent.com&prompt=select_account&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.mydomain.com%2F_oauth&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&state=fc4c85a1e11f4914247d1e7c95b031%3Agoogle%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftraefik.mydomain.com%2Fdashboard [following]
--2020-09-26 19:19:38--  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=6597114190-33npkhvge44jtcrj4scmuafgt561.apps.googleusercontent.com&prompt=select_account&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth.mydomain.com%2F_oauth&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&state=fc4c85a1e11f4914247d1e7c94a5b031%3Agoogle%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftraefik.mydomain.com%2Fdashboard
Resolving accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)... 172.217.1.205, 2607:f8b0:400f:805::200d
Connecting to accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)|172.217.1.205|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?oauth=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fsignin%2Foauth%2Flegacy%2Fconsent%3Fauthuser%3Dunknown%26part%3DAJi8hAPSHE1cMVuaeTQ61pcXpMEfDhbxN02IAjg5jH0GYWG7yCVc5EC9ug_kuK3j7hUBGCiY_q_SGL-0xSPDtiliIthwpmOTvP_MV5upFvDdYTpTTlraXSxx_7f8vhJteA8UjJoKSqgeUvFWns_BdFn8z73XALchawMrWA1vVl0xJYpUYHUXxD3K0zl4TbcgpVOljSfZM0vkQAHwTm54OjNiw51GTMCJAwiGwh_ANodLXY1n07UrO6-AgJ1pEeRksrlKs-O2W2Az1Fj4QWMej3OJ8HiHfRVlBt8c8zStbROoFMIce9ldHm5FF-l54b3xQcBp4xLi6ABqcrciv_Y0TAFuuwwotfgqrl1_uMHfyX9KJogk_gntcEiG2489OMNwFinOVAPUCg1Z-gn-ps7g_oBl4MB-FzsIiVpfyy_qRD7SMyhvnVe4Bj-%26as%3DS-2012888342%253A160116957872%23 [following]
--2020-09-26 19:19:38--  https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?oauth=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fsignin%2Foauth%2Flegacy%2Fconsent%3Fauthuser%3Dunknown%26part%3DAJi8hAPSk6oHE1cMVRfegIuaeTQ61pcXpMEfD2FXah02IAjg5GYWG7yCVc5EC9ug_kuK3j7hUBGCiY_q_SGL-0xSPDtiliIthwpmOTvP_MV5upFvDdYTpTTSxx_7f8vhJteA8UjJoKSqgeUvFWns_BdFn8z73XALchawMrWA1vVXbAl0xJYpUYHUXzl4TbcgpVOljSfZM0vkQAHwTmhD54OjNiw51GTMCJAwiGwh_ANodLXY1n07UrO6-AgJ1pEeRksrlKs-O2W2Az1Fj4QWMej3OJ8HiHfRVlBt8c8zStbROoFMIce9ldHm5FF-l54b3xQcBpABqcrciv_Y0TAFuuwwotfgqrl1_uMHfyX9KJogk_gntcEiG2489OMNwFAPUCg1Z-gn-ps7g_oBl4MB-FzsIiVpfyy_qRDBteJ7SMyhvnVe4Bj-%26as%3DS-2012888342%253A1601169578900872%23
Reusing existing connection to accounts.google.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fsignin%2Foauth%2Flegacy%2Fconsent%3Fauthuser%3Dunknown%26part%3DAJi8hAPSkE1cMVRIuaeTQ61ppMEfD2FXahbxN02IAjg5jH0GYWG7yCVc5EC9ug_kuK3j7hUBGCiY_q_SGL-0xSPDtiliIthwpmOTvP_MV5upFvDdYTpTTlraXSxx_7f8vhJteA8UjJoKSqgs_BdFn8z73XALchawMrWA1vVXbAl0xJYpUYHUXxD3K0zl4TbcgpVOljSfZM0vkQAHwTmhD54OjNiw51GTMCJAwiGwh_ANodLXY1n07UrO6-AgJ1pEeRksrlKs-O2W2Az1Fj4QWMej3OJ8HiHBt8c8zStbROoFMIce9ldHm5FF-l54b3xQcBp4xLi6ABqcrciv_Y0TAFuuwwotfgqrl1_uMHfyX9KJntcEiG2489OMNwFinOVAPUCg1Z-gn-ps7g_oBl4MB-FzsIiVpfyy_qRDBteJ7SMyhvnVe4Bj-%26as%3DS-2012888342%253A1601178900872%23&sacu=1&oauth=1&rip=1 [following]
--2020-09-26 19:19:39--  https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fsignin%2Foauth%2Flegacy%2Fconsent%3Fauthuser%3Dunknown%26part%3DAJi8hAPSk6ogIuaeTQ61pcXpMEfD2FXahbxN02IAjg5jH0GYWG7yCVc5EC9ug_kuK3j7hUBGCiY_q_SGL-0xSPDtiliIthwpmOTvP_MV5upFvDdYTpTTlraXSxx_7f8vhJteA8UjJoKSqgeUvFWns_BdFn8z73XALchawMrWA1vVXbAl0xJYpUYHUXxD3K0zl4jSfZM0vkQAHwTmhD54OjNiw51GTMCJAwiGwh_ANodLXY1n07UrO6-AgJ1pEeRksrlKs-O2W2Az1Fj4QWMej3OVlBt8c8zStbROoFMIce9ldHm5FF-l54b3xQcBp4xLi6ABqcrciv_Y0TAFuuwwotfgqrl1_uKJogk_gntcEiG2489OMNwFinOVAPUCg1Z-gn-ps7g_oBl4MB-FzsIiVpfyy_qRDBteJ7SMyhvnVe4Bj-%26as%3DS-2012888342%253A1601169578900872%23&sacu=1&oauth=1&rip=1
Reusing existing connection to accounts.google.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘dashboard.1’

dashboard.1                                  [ <=>                                                                             ]  58.82K  --.-KB/s    in 0.03s   

2020-09-26 19:19:39 (1.64 MB/s) - ‘dashboard.1’ saved [60236]
```

The Docker log says:

> level=debug msg="Remote error http://oauth:4181. StatusCode: 307"
> middlewareType=ForwardedAuthType middlewareName=middlewares-oauth@file

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.3"

########################### NETWORKS
networks:
  t2_proxy:
    external:
      name: t2_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge

########################### SERVICES
services:
# All services / apps go below this line

# Traefik 2 - Reverse Proxy
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:chevrotin # the chevrotin tag refers to v2.2.x but introduced a breaking change in 2.2.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: # CLI arguments
      - --global.checkNewVersion=true
      - --global.sendAnonymousUsage=false
      - --entryPoints.http.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.https.address=:443
        # Allow these IPs to set the X-Forwarded-* headers - Cloudflare IPs: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/
      - --entrypoints.https.forwardedHeaders.trustedIPs=173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22,141.101.64.0/18,108.162.192.0/18,190.93.240.0/20,188.114.96.0/20,197.234.240.0/22,198.41.128.0/17,162.158.0.0/15,104.16.0.0/12,172.64.0.0/13,131.0.72.0/22
      - --entryPoints.traefik.address=:8080
      - --api=true
#      - --api.insecure=true
#      - --serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true
      - --log=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG # (Default: error) DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
      - --accessLog=true
      - --accessLog.filePath=/traefik.log
      - --accessLog.bufferingSize=100 # Configuring a buffer of 100 lines
      - --accessLog.filters.statusCodes=400-499
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - --providers.docker.defaultrule=Host(`{{ index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}.$DOMAINNAME`)
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=t2_proxy
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=false
      - --providers.file.directory=/rules # Load dynamic configuration from one or more .toml or .yml files in a directory.
#      - --providers.file.filename=/path/to/file # Load dynamic configuration from a file.
      - --providers.file.watch=true # Only works on top level files in the rules folder
#      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.caServer=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory # LetsEncrypt Staging Server - uncomment when testing
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.email=$CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.storage=/acme.json
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnsChallenge.provider=cloudflare
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnsChallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1:53,1.0.0.1:53
#    networks:
#      t2_proxy:
#        ipv4_address: 192.168.90.254 # You can specify a static IP
    networks:
      - t2_proxy
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/rules:/rules 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/acme/acme.json:/acme.json # cert location - you must touch this file and change permissions to 600
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/traefik.log:/traefik.log # for fail2ban - make sure to touch file before starting container
      - $DOCKERDIR/shared:/shared
    environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=$CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL
      - CF_API_KEY=$CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # HTTP-to-HTTPS Redirect
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      # HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.rule=Host(`traefik.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls=true"
#      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.certResolver=dns-cloudflare" # Comment out this line after first run of traefik to force the use of wildcard certs
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[0].main=$DOMAINNAME"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[0].sans=*.$DOMAINNAME"
#      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[1].main=$SECONDDOMAINNAME" # Pulls main cert for second domain
#      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[1].sans=*.$SECONDDOMAINNAME" # Pulls wildcard cert for second domain
      ## Services - API
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.service=api@internal"
      ## Middlewares    
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.middlewares=chain-oauth@file"
# Google OAuth - Single Sign On using OAuth 2.0
  oauth:
    container_name: oauth
    image: thomseddon/traefik-forward-auth:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - t2_proxy
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    environment:
      - CLIENT_ID=$GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
      - CLIENT_SECRET=$GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
      - SECRET=$OAUTH_SECRET
      - COOKIE_DOMAIN=$DOMAINNAME
      - INSECURE_COOKIE=false
      - AUTH_HOST=oauth.$DOMAINNAME
      - URL_PATH=/_oauth
      - WHITELIST=$MY_EMAIL
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - LOG_FORMAT=text
      - LIFETIME=2592000 # 30 days
      - DEFAULT_ACTION=auth
      - DEFAULT_PROVIDER=google
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      ## HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-rtr.rule=Host(`oauth.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-rtr.tls=true"
      ## HTTP Services
      - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-rtr.service=oauth-svc"
      - "traefik.http.services.oauth-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=4181"
      ## Middlewares
      - "traefik.http.routers.oauth-rtr.middlewares=chain-oauth@file"
```

Finally, the end of my middlewares.toml file looks like this:

```
  [http.middlewares.middlewares-oauth]
    [http.middlewares.middlewares-oauth.forwardAuth]
      address = "http://oauth:4181" # Make sure you have the OAuth service in docker-compose.yml
      trustForwardHeader = true
      authResponseHeaders = ["X-Forwarded-User"]
```

I searched around and checked everything I found already suggested but no luck. Seems like it's gotta be something small though.

Answer (score 0):

In Cloudflare, I changed oauth.mydomain.com from "Proxied" to "DNS Only" and now I am no longer getting redirected.